# setup an ftp on linux?

Tags: linux, ftp

Is there a simple way to setup an ftp? I am trying to not go crazy and eat up my ram. A friend doesnt know linux at all and he is doing the art on my site. I'd like to have him access `/var/www/sitename/`.

What permissions do i need to set and how do i create a user for him. I heard i can use sshd process to do it but i have no clue how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your friend uses Windows, have them use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) to access your server via SSH.  Accessing user accounts via an unencrypted protocol is a security risk.

If you do not know how to connect to the server, perhaps you should contact the administrator of the server or support department of the ISP providing it.  [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) is a good Windows client and most UNIX based operating systems include SSH clients by default.

`useradd username` to add an account.  Read the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd).

`passwd username` to set his password.  Read the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/passwd).

`groupadd groupname` to create a group.  Read the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/groupadd).

`vigr` to add your username and their username to the group.  Read the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vigr).

`chgrp -R groupname /var/www/sitename` to change group ownership on the web tree.

**You can use the `find` commands below here instead of the next chmod commands**

`chmod g+s /var/www/sitename` *and any other directory within that tree* to make default ownership be groupname on permission, which will allow you both to work there.

Then, make group writeable:

`chmod -R g+w /var/www/sitename`

This is the quick way to set the permissions as I describe above:

```
find /var/www/sitename -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
find /var/www/sitename -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

Following that, you will both be able to SSH to the server and modify files within that directory.

Comment: Unfortunately i cant use WinSCP as it locks up due to a prompt after connecting to the server http://serverfault.com/questions/159114/ide-for-ssh-linux-with-a-shell

Comment: I can connect just fine. I havent tried upload anything myself but i know he'll need to. I am using putty.

Comment: After i figured out how to connect directly i was able to use winscp and your solution worked perfect.